# How is sysfs updated when a GPIO changes state?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt, gpio, sysfs

Assume that the gpio X can be exported in sysfs as an input pin, after doing that a directory called gpioX will be created into /sys/class/gpio/. gpioX/ contains few file such as "value" which represents the current state of the gpio X (high or low).

What happens (in kernel space) when the signal applied to the pin X changes its state (for example from low to high)?

I mean, before the transition gpioX/value contains "low", but after that it will contain "high" value. How is this file updated by the OS?

I think that an interrupt mechanism is required.Does it use an interrupt mechanism to update sysfs?

Comment: I put together some notes about sysfs and the pseudo files in an answer to this question, [what is the /sys/class/gpio/export and `/sys/class/gpio/unexport mechanism and what is the underlying sysfs functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63769403/what-is-the-sys-class-gpio-export-and-sys-class-gpio-unexport-mechanism-and-w). It doesn't exactly answer your question however there are some thoughts on the underlying sysfs functionality that someone may find helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How is this file updated by the OS? I think that an interrupt mechanism is required.

It does not require an interrupt mechanism unless it supports polling ([man poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)) or alternate *asynchronous* notifications.  At least with most version, the */sys/class/gpio/* only does a read of the GPIO level when someone reads the file.

*sysfs*, *debugfs*, *configfs*, *procfs*, etc are virtual file systems.  When you access the file, code within the Linux kernel runs to provide the value. *sysfs* only provides a file like interface; that doesn't mean it is *backed* with actual state.  The state is the GPIO level which can be read at any time.

[gpio_value_show()](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c?id=refs/tags/v3.12-rc7#n246) appears to be the current implementation.  What you describe with interrupts is possible.  It can be done through the `sysfs_set_active_low()` function or the *sysfs* file */sys/class/gpio/gpioN/edge*.  Writing to the file may return an error if the GPIO doesn't support interrupts.  See [gpio.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt) for more (especially for your particular version of Linux).

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar except that I am using Kotlin under Android on a DragonBoard 410C. The documentation talks about using the `poll(2)` system service of Linux to monitor the `/sys/class/gpio/gpionn/value` pseudo file for an event after setting the `/sys/class/gpio/gpionn/edge` pseudo file. [how to use poll(2) or select(2) service call to watch a pseudo file for changes with Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64028130/how-to-use-poll2-with-kotlin-files)

Comment: Do you have the `edge` file?  If not, then `poll()` is not supported. The hardware has to be able to generate an interrupt on a gpio change.  All hardware will allow read of the current gpio value, but only some hardware will support an interrupt (and `edge` and `poll()`).  If `edge` does not exist, then running `poll()` on `value` will do nothing.

Comment: Yes, the `edge` pseudo file does exist for the GPIO pins. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to use the `poll(2)` service call from Kotlin source code. I've found something to try later this evening and if it works then I'll create an answer to my posted question. I just thought you might be able to point me in the right direction. Take care and enjoy your day.