# How to implement blocking call without wasting CPU time?

Tags: linux, interrupt

I have some HW resource which triggers an interrupt when finished.
I want to implement a function `activateHw()` which would return only when the action is finished (meaning, when the interrupt is triggered) but I don't want it to waste CPU time (no interrupt polling). Basically, what I want is:

```
bool activateHw() {
    trigger_hw();
    sleep_until_interrupt_arrived();
    return true;
}
```

How can I achieve that in Linux?

Comment: Are you in kernel space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a wait queue. In the interrupt handler you wake up the waiting thread. That way you will not waste resources (eg. using a spin lock).

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://linuxinme.blogspot.co.at/2007/06/wait-queues.html).

Take a look at the linux source, an example usage would be `/drivers/char/hpet.c` or `drivers/char/rtc.c`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing a kernel module, you can use `request_irq()` to set up a callback / interrupt handler. Your interrupt handler can write the data to character device. Your blocking function just needs to call the `poll` syscall on the character device. It will block and sleep till data is available.

Have a look at [gpio.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio.txt) , specifically how gpio pins can be setup to write to /sys/.../gpioxx/value by configuring what edge should trigger the interupt. This can be used for userspace code as well if the programme is not too time critical.

[here is a SO question that seemed related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744811/how-is-sysfs-updated-when-a-gpio-change-state).